# Strange charaters in JSON from node server prevents parsing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have this function on my node server:

```
     /* some code */

router.get('/check', function(req,res) {
    var filename = req.query.fname;
    console.log(filename);
    var from = './files/'+filename;
    var obj = fs.readFileSync(from, 'utf8');

    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    console.log(obj);
    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    res.render('choosevar',{
        names: obj
    });
});
```

On the client side I have some javascript, which use JSON object from server:

```
<h1>GIG</h1>
<script>
    var str = '<%= names%>';
    console.log(str);
    str = str.replace(/&#34;/g,'"')
    console.log(JSON.parse(str));
</script>
```

It works, but as you can see I have to call `replace` on it first, because every quote in names are " .

Why is it occur?

Comment: Can you post a example JSON response before you do a replace on it?

Comment: It happens because the *unspecified* template language you are using, at least when you are using the output syntax you have there, is expecting you to be generating typical HTML with it and it escapes `"` to make them safe to use in attribute values (as a standard defense against XSS).

Comment: @lightswitch05 [{&#34;x0&#34;:&#34;№ п/п&#34;,&#34;x1&#34;:&#34;Прізвище, імя студента&#34;,&#34;x2&#34;:&#34;Вік&#34;   ////.....

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, but how to solve it without replacing?

Comment: @IvanMikho — You haven't even told us the name of the template language. That makes it quite hard to explain how to make it behave differently.

Comment: @Quentin, in my json I use ukranian language and utf8 encoding, but what is template language?

Comment: The language the last block of code you included is written in, which defines what `<%=` means.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks I try do it!